# creating Pie Chart - argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I cannot understand why I get the following error when creating a pie chart?

```
labels = c('payroll', 'wins')
pie(as.numeric(by(payroll,wins)),labels)
```

> Error in FUN(dd[x, ], ...) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no
>   default

payroll

400000
320000
500000

wins

50
24
53

Comment: the error comes from the `by` part in your code. Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We have no idea what the variables payroll and wins are.

Comment: `by` needs a `FUN` argument (see `?by`); what did you expect `by(payroll, wins)` to do? At the moment you're telling R to do something with `payroll` by`wins` groups without specifying what that something this.

Comment: I only want to create a pie chart?  is it possible to create a pie chart with two variables?  Or I can create a pie chart with either payroll or wins?